# Element UI default theme using incorrect font path on NPM

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, element-ui

Using Laravel Mix, I am unable to get my Element UI installation to correctly find the fonts path. It returns a relative URL to the font path instead of starting at the root. I am using Element UI v2.9.1 and Vue 2.6.10

I have already attempted to set the font path myself in a custom SASS theme and copy the font directory using Mix

```js
.js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js'
    ], 'js/backend.js')
```

This is in my `webpack.mix.js`

```js
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale';
import lang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';

window.Vue = Vue;
locale.use(lang);
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })
```

This is what's in my app.js

No matter what page I visit on my website the URL requested is already like

```
http://example.test/admin/my-uri/fonts/vendor/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/element-icons.ttf?732389ded34cb9c52dd88271f1345af9
```

However the fonts are correctly deployed to `public/fonts/vendor/element-ui`

Answer (score 0):

Run...

```
npm i element-ui
```

In /resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('element-ui');
```

In /resources/sass/app.scss

```
@import '~element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
```

Run...

```
npm run prod
```

Don't do any importing inside webpack.mix.js.